# Ansible: playbook name and task step index on variables

Tags: ansible

In my playbook I have several shell task per playbook, like ten or more. I want to use creates shell arg to avoid executing them over and over.

Currently I have this:

```
- name: Download sonar-runner
  get_url:
    url: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/runner/sonar-   runner-dist/2.4/sonar-runner-dist-2.4.zip
    dest: /tmp
    mode: 0755

- name: Unarchive
  unarchive:
    src: /tmp/sonar-runner-dist-2.4.zip
    dest: /opt/tools/sonar-runner-2.4

- name: Sym link
  shell: ln -s sonar-runner-2.4 sonar-runner
  args:
    creates: ~/.ansible/sonar-runner.task/step.3

- name: Configure profile
  shell: |
    echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/' > /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    echo 'export M2_HOME=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.5.3' >> /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    echo 'export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}' >> /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
  args:
    creates: ~/.ansible/sonar-runner.task/step.4
```

Is there any way to achieve this using variables. I'm thinking something like this:

```
- name: Sym link
  shell: ln -s sonar-runner-2.4 sonar-runner
  args:
    creates: ~/.ansible/{{playbook_name}}/{{task_index}}

- name: Configure profile
  shell: |
    echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/' > /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    echo 'export M2_HOME=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.5.3' >> /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    echo 'export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}' >> /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
  args:
    creates: ~/.ansible/{{playbook_name}}/{{task_index}}
```

Is there any way to do this? Am I missing something? Or isn't that the way Ansible works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I've managed to solve this using a mix of vars, facts and roles.

*testfacts.yml playbook*

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    current_role: 'testfacts'
  roles:
    - testfacts
```

*roles/testfacts/tasks/main.yml*

```
---
- name: Import task1
  import_tasks: task1.yml

- name: Import task2
  import_tasks: task2.yml
```

*roles/testfacts/tasks/task1.yml*

```
---

- name: Prepare task
  include_role:
    name: common
    tasks_from: set_facts
  vars:
    current_task: 'task1'  

- name: Test facts in task step 1
  shell: "echo foo > /home/awx/outp"
  args:
    creates: "{{ creates_dir }}/test-fact-tasks-step-1"

# this never gets executed
- name: Test facts in task 2 step 2 
  shell: "echo bar > /home/awx/outp"
  args:
    creates: "{{ creates_dir }}/test-fact-tasks-step-1"
```

*roles/common/tasks/set_facts.yml*

```
---
- name: set_facts
  set_fact: 
    creates_dir: "{{ bookeeping_dir }}/roles.d/{{ current_role }}/tasks.d/{{ current_task }}/steps.d"
```

*inventories/prod/group_vars/group_vars.yml*

```
---
bookeeping_dir: /home/awx/.ansible/ansible_bookeeping
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this? Am I missing something? Or isn't that the way Ansible works?

Yes, yes, and no :-)

> Is there any way to do this?

The `shell:` and `command:` support inline `creates=` declarations, so you can keep all of that together in one block (and thus it is a candidate for being a variable, or a yaml anchor):

```
- shell: |
    creates=/etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    echo 'hello' > /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
- command: |
    creates=/etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    cp /something /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

However, I just told you that for your information, and for the circumstances where these next set of steps won't work because ...

> Am I missing something?

You want to use the built-in idempotency whenever possible, to get you out of the business of having to do manual "has this task run" bookkeeping. Thus:

```
- file:
    src: sonar-runner-2.4
    dest: sonar-runner
    state: link
- copy:
    dest: /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    content: |
        export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
        export M2_HOME=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.5.3
        export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

I'm genuinely surprised ansible didn't whine when you tried to use `ln` manually, as it knows about common shell commands and will nudge you to switch to the built-in module `file:`

Comment: The playbook posted was a section of a larger one. I guess some of the shell calls could be replaced with ansible modules but not all of them. I was looking for a way to make things easier when the bookkeping is unavoidable.